# Django - Limit select field to queryset of foreign table?

Tags: django, filtering, django-queryset

I have two models as follows:

```
System_Contact
    first_name
    last_name
    isOwner = CharField ('Y'/'N')
    isMainContact = CharField ('Y'/'N')

System
    mainContact = ForeignKey(System_Contact)
    owner = ForeignKey(System_Contact)
    billTo = ForeignKey(System_Contact)
```

So, when I show the `System` form in a web page, the user can select the `mainContact` `owner` and `billTo` contacts from a drop down menu to save to the `System` model. However, I want to filter the select fields in the `System` form so that they are like this:

```
mainContact Select box: -- only show System_Contacts that have isMainContact = 'Y'
owner Select Box: -- only show Syste_Contacts that have isOwner = 'Y'
```

As it is now, I know how to limit a select box by filtering the queryset, but I don't know how to filter the related Foreign Key querySet. Since the `mainContact` and `owner` fields  are Foreign Keys, I need to filter the Foreign Table (`System_Contact`), not the table on which the form is built (`System`)

I know how to filter a normal, non Foreign Key type select box as follows:

```
form.fields["some_field"].queryset = Some_Model.objects.filter(some_field="Foo")
```

How would I 'extend' this so that it filters the Foreign table?

This is what I am trying currently, without success:

```
form.fields["mainContact"].queryset = System_Contact.objects.filter(isMainContact = 'Y')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is what I am trying currently, without success:

```
form.fields["mainContact"].queryset = System_Contact.objects.filter(isMainContact = 'Y')
```

Can you include your model form and view? That looks OK to me.

Another approach is to override the `__init__` method of your model form and set the queryset there.

```
class SystemForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SystemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["mainContact"].queryset = System_Contact.objects.filter(isMainContact = 'Y')
    class Meta:
        model = System
```

As an aside, I would recommend using a [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#booleanfield) instead of a `CharField` with 'Y' and 'N' as choices.

Answer (score 1):

That syntax looks correct. Are you receiving an error or is it just not filtering and showing everybody? Try the System_Contact.objects.get(id=`<some valid id>`) to see if it gets only one or more. If it gets more, perhaps it is being populated from a different call than the one intended.

Answer (score 1):

Well this is embarrassing...

As I was pasting in my view and model form as per `Alasdair's` request, I noticed my error. Here is my (incorrect) view:

```
def system_contacts(request, systemID):
    sys = System.objects.get(pk=systemID)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = System_Contacts_Form(request.POST, instance=sys)
        form.fields["systemOwner"].queryset = System_Contact.objects.filter(systemOwner__exact='Y')
        form.fields["mainContact"].queryset = System_Contact.objects.filter(isMainContact__exact = 'Y')
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/systems/')
    else:
        conts = Contact_List.objects.filter(systemID = sys.pk)
        form = System_Contacts_Form(instance=sys)
    return render_to_response('pages/systems/system_pages/contacts.html', {'sys':sys, 'form':form, 'conts':conts}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I had put the `form.fields["systemOwner"]...` part in the `POST` section of the view, not the `GET` section of the view.

Here is my corrected view:

```
def system_contacts(request, systemID):
    sys = System.objects.get(pk=systemID)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = System_Contacts_Form(request.POST, instance=sys)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/systems/')
    else:
        conts = Contact_List.objects.filter(systemID = sys.pk)
        form = System_Contacts_Form(instance=sys)
        form.fields["systemOwner"].queryset = System_Contact.objects.filter(systemOwner__exact='Y')
        form.fields["mainContact"].queryset = System_Contact.objects.filter(isMainContact__exact = 'Y')
    return render_to_response('pages/systems/system_pages/contacts.html', {'sys':sys, 'form':form, 'conts':conts}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now my corrected view works and the filtering works on the `select` inputs on the form. I would not have thought to look at that without your help.

Cheers :-)